# Fetching drives of Microsoft Teams group/team after creating Plan

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-planner

I am using Microsoft Graph API to

```
1) Create Team and Channels
2) Installing an App
3) Adding Plans, buckets, and tasks to the planner app
4) Copy items from another Drive to the newly created channels drive.
```

My code is executing in this order

```
1) Create Group and Team
2) Create Channel under team
3) Create Plan in Planner   **/planner/plans**
4) Install another app
5) adding buckets and tasks to the created PLan
6) get list of drives using `groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children`
7) Copy items to drive of Created channel
```

So the problem in this order is that point 7 only return drive of the General chanel and not for the 
newly created channel.

But if I change this code execution order to

```
1> 2>7>4>3>5>6>7
```

then it returns all drives on fetching drives step.

So in my finding its problem in creating a plan before to fetch the drives. it works if I a fetching drives before creating the Plan in the planner.
Why this is behaving like this.

What should be the right order of code execution so that all works as expected?

Comment: What error you are getting while fetching the drives? is the error code is 401?

Comment: First time access to a user's personal drive through the Microsoft Graph before the user accesses their personal site through a browser leads to a 401 response. it is a known issue.